# form action not working inside php class function

Tags: php

i have class promotions in `class_promotions.php`

```
class Promotion{ 

  function promotionForm(){ 

     <form method="post" action="  admin_panel.php?admin=admin-pro&admin=addpro   ">         
        Title: <input type="text" name="title" />        
        Description: <input type="text" name="des" />        
        <input type="submit" name="title" />     

     </form> 

  }    

  //and the 2nd function in same class is     
  function insertPromotions(){     
    //this function will get the val from admin_panel.php page and insert val to database
  }    

}
```

as i submit that form in address bar link showing is

```
"admin_panel.php?title=field-val&des=field-val"
```

but i need the link at the submission for form is something like

```
"admin_panel.php?admin=admin-pro&admin=addpro&title=field-val&des=field-val"
```

how to get that link after submitting that form, from that specific function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hidden` like this:

```
<form method="get" action="admin_panel.php">
<input type="hidden" name="admin" value="admin-pro"> 
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar">
```

A document for `hidden` is here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

And if you would like to have your parameters append to your action url, you can use `method="get"`.

```
<form method="get" action="admin_panel.php">
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I +1 but i think you should link to the documentation on `<input type="hidden" />`